# Color Specified Edges and Vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks, style

Is there a more efficient way to code the specifying of selected vertices and edges than listing them separately as shown below?

[image]

```
edges = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 5, 4 -> 6, 
   4 -> 7, 5 -> 7, 5 -> 8, 5 -> 9, 6 -> 7, 6 -> 9, 7 -> 9, 8 -> 9};
Graph[edges, GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> 0.45, 
 VertexStyle -> {1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 9 -> Lighter[Lighter[Lighter[Lighter[Yellow]]]], 
   4 | 6 -> Lighter[Lighter[Red]]}, 
 EdgeStyle -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 3 | 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 | 1 \[DirectedEdge] 4 | 
     2 \[DirectedEdge] 3 | 2 \[DirectedEdge] 4 | 4 \[DirectedEdge] 6 | 
     3 \[DirectedEdge] 6 | 4 \[DirectedEdge] 5 | 4 \[DirectedEdge] 7 | 
     5 \[DirectedEdge] 9 | 5 \[DirectedEdge] 8 | 5 \[DirectedEdge] 7 | 
     8 \[DirectedEdge] 9 | 7 \[DirectedEdge] 9 | 3 \[DirectedEdge] 4 -> Blue, 
   1 \[DirectedEdge] 6 | 6 \[DirectedEdge] 9 -> Red}, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 13]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a default color using blank pattern `_ -> color`  or just `color` first in the list followed by exceptions as follows :

```
VertexStyle -> {Lighter[Yellow, 1 - (2/3)^4], 4 | 6 -> Lighter[Lighter[Red]]}

EdgeStyle -> {Blue,   1\[DirectedEdge] 6 | 6\[DirectedEdge] 9 -> Red}
```

alternatively

```
VertexStyle -> {_ -> Lighter[Yellow, 1 - (2/3)^4],  4 | 6 -> Lighter[Lighter[Red]]}

EdgeStyle -> {_ -> Blue,   1\[DirectedEdge] 6 | 6\[DirectedEdge] 9 -> Red}
```

Comment: thank you very much kglr!!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative is to use `MapAt[]` to apply `Style[]` directly to the "special" vertices and edges, and leave the default colors in `EdgeStyle`/`VertexStyle`. For instance,

```
 Graph[MapAt[Style[#, Nest[Lighter, Red, 2]] &, Range[9], {{4}, {6}}],
       MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, edges, Position[edges, (1 -> 6) | (6 -> 9)]],
       EdgeStyle -> Blue, 
       GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}, 
       VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 13],
       VertexSize -> 0.45, VertexStyle -> Nest[Lighter, Yellow, 4]]
```

[image: colored graph]